# Clicking an image in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently when the mouse is dragged over a cell, the code below will highlight permissible cells to drag the selected piece to.

I need to modify the code to include clicking as well. For example, when the mouse is dragged over a cell, permissible cells are highlighted. When the same cell is clicked the permissible cells will remain highlighted until either the original cell is clicked again or until one of the highlighted locations is click where upon the image will appear. How can I do this?

Thanks.

[Current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/42/).

HTML:

```
<table border="1" id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td ></td>
    <td  bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
    <td class="items  p1 p3"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-  scraps/32/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
    <td class="items  p1"></td>
    <td class="items p3" bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="piece" id="p1" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png"></td>
    <td bgcolor=#000000 ></td>
    <td class="piece" id="p3" ><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/soft-scraps/32/Button-Blank-Gray-icon.png" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('img').draggable({  });
$('#tbl td').droppable({
  hoverClass: 'over',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(this).css("background-color")==='rgb(255, 255, 0)') {
      $(this).children('img').remove();
      var cell = ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
        'left': '0',
        'top': '0'
      });
      $('img').draggable('disable');
    } else {
      ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
    $("td").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $("."+id).css("background", "");
    });
  }
});
$(".piece").mouseover(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("."+id).css("background", "yellow");
}).mouseleave(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  $("."+id).css("background", "");
});
```

Comment: never accepted an answer for your previous questions? What's with that?

Comment: As you can see I am new to stackoverflow. I did not know I am suppose to accept an answer. Thanks for kindly pointing it out. Should I accept them now to move on?

Comment: yes accept answers . It's a sign of disrespect so people won't help you further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this adds the functionality you're looking for:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/45/)

**JS**

```
var imgs = $('img'); 

imgs.draggable({  });

$('#tbl td').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'over',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var cell = $(this); 
        var img = ui.draggable;

        if (cell.hasClass("yellow")) {      
          cell.children('img').remove();
          img.appendTo(cell).css({
            'left': '0',
            'top': '0'
          });
          img.draggable('disable');
        } else {                     
          img.draggable('option','revert',true);      
        }

        $('.yellow').removeClass('yellow');  

        setUpHover(); 
    }
});

imgs.click(function(){
  //the image we just clicked on
  var img = $(this); 
  //The cells we can move our image to.
  var cells = $("." + img.parent().attr('id'));

  //disable dragging of other images while this one is in focus
  imgs.not(img).draggable('disable');
  //disable the hover event so that we don't lose our highlighted cells
  imgs.unbind('hover'); 
  //add a dynamic click event to the cells we're allowed to click on. 
  cells.click(function(){
    //re-enable dragging for all images
    imgs.draggable('enable'); 
    //remove the dynamic click event and remove the yellow background
    cells.unbind('click').removeClass('yellow'); 
    //add the image to the cell. 
    $(this).html(img); 
    //re-bind the hover event.
    setUpHover(); 
  }); 
}); 

function setUpHover(){
  imgs.unbind('hover').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("."+id).addClass("yellow");
  }, function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("."+id).removeClass("yellow");       
  });
} 
setUpHover();
```

**CSS**

```
#tbl td { width:32px; height:32px;}
.over { background-color: red; }
.yellow {
  background-color:yellow !important;     
}
```

Comment: Wow! Brandon, Thank you so much. I have been working hours and hours on this. The comments are great too. Is there a way to "un-highlight" the cells on a second mouse click if the user chooses not to move the original piece clicked? I am playing around with your code now and am learning so much. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to un-highlight the cells when the user clicks but it does not seem to work correctly. Any ideas? Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/bLb3H/47/

Comment: Glad my initial answer got you going. Sorry for my non-responsiveness, but I've been quite busy the last few days. You may need to decouple the business logic from the UI inorder to accomplish all your goals. I'll see if I can take a look sometime tonight or tomorrow.